# Timecop does not work with DateTime attributes defined in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, timecop

I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    due_date 7.days.from_now
  end
end
```

In my specs, I'm using Timecop in this way:

```
before do
  Timecop.freeze(Time.parse("Oct 5 2015"))
end
```

Time.now and Date.today are being stubbed with the given time as expected, but the due_date attribute of the factory always returns based on the date of the system, and I would like it to return based on the date provided in Timecop. Is it possible?

I'm using Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 3.2.22, Timecop 0.8.0 and Rspec 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the value to a block, so that it's evaluated on call, not when the factories definition is loaded. This is called `Lazy attributes`, more about that [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    due_date { 7.days.from_now }
  end
end
```